# Dynamically add pre populated forms from database using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

Ive been researching online for a couple days and I cant seem to find out the answer to my question. I would like to append a div or insert a pre populated form from my database depending on a drop down menu (selecting from a row in my DB). Once you press a button it will add the form field to a div or area above. Any suggestions? How should I tackle this? Im extremely new to Jquery and Ajax but know PHP fairly well.

Comment: Are you asking how to access rows from your DB using Jquery.ajax() with PHP?

Comment: Well more like how to access the row, display certain information of the row (in a form format) and append it to a div. @mccallbear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to populate the fields when the page is being loaded. (pass the values on to your html page with `"value=<$php echo $someData %>"`

if you want to load the data without refreshing the page each time, I'd suggest you make a different page that will load the data from the database through POST-requests and retrieve the data as JSON, so you can parse it with Javascript and update the fields accordingly.

updating the fields can be done like so:

```
json = YourJSONData;    
$('.some-class').val(json['someData']); // if populating a form field
$('.some-other-class').html(json['someOtherData'); // if populating a div or other DOM element.
```

etc...

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you for responding.... so creating a PHP page with basic MYSQL select configuration I understand. But how do you connect that php page with jquery using ajax and json?

Comment: by making another page with PHP which will output data formatted as JSON depending on the POST-data it receives. So basically send a POST request to another page which will handle the data in the POST request and output data formatted as JSON to that page, which in return will be retrieved with the ajax query (ajax simply retrieves the html/json/(other markup languages etc.) it finds on the page you send it to)